CORS issue with Keyrock GE in Fiware: POST requests for logging in users work, but CORS error occurs with other requests
I configured the Keyrock Generic Enabler (GE) in Fiware to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). While POST requests for logging in users function correctly without CORS issues, attempting different requests such as creating users results in a CORS error.
Docker-compose config for Keyrock:
version: "3.8"
services:
  orion-v2:
    image: quay.io/fiware/orion:${ORION_VERSION}
    hostname: orion
    container_name: fiware-orion
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.1.9
    expose:
      - "${ORION_PORT}"
    ports:
      - "${ORION_PORT}:${ORION_PORT}" # localhost:1026
    command: -logLevel DEBUG -noCache -dbhost mongo-db -corsOrigin __ALL
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail -s http://orion:${ORION_PORT}/version || exit 1
      interval: 5s
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 60s
        max_attempts: 10

  iot-agent:
    image: fiware/iotagent-json
    hostname: iot-agent
    container_name: fiware-iot-agent
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db
      - orion-v2
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.1.100
    ports:
      - "${IOTA_NORTH_PORT}:${IOTA_NORTH_PORT}" # localhost:4041
      - "${IOTA_SOUTH_PORT}:${IOTA_SOUTH_PORT}" # localhost:7896
    environment:
      - IOTA_CB_HOST=orion-proxy
      - IOTA_CB_PORT=${ORION_PROXY_PORT} # port the context broker listens on to update context
      - IOTA_NORTH_PORT=${IOTA_NORTH_PORT}
      - IOTA_REGISTRY_TYPE=mongodb #Whether to hold IoT device info in memory or in a database
      - IOTA_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG # The log level of the IoT Agent
      - IOTA_TIMESTAMP=true # Supply timestamp information with each measurement
      - IOTA_CB_NGSI_VERSION=v2 # use NGSIv2 when sending updates for active attributes
      - IOTA_AUTOCAST=true # Ensure Ultralight number values are read as numbers not strings
      - IOTA_MONGO_HOST=mongo-db # The host name of MongoDB
      - IOTA_MONGO_PORT=${MONGO_DB_PORT} # The port mongoDB is listening on
      - IOTA_MONGO_DB=iotagentjson # The name of the database used in mongoDB
      - IOTA_HTTP_PORT=${IOTA_SOUTH_PORT} # The port used for device traffic over HTTP
      - IOTA_PROVIDER_URL=http://iot-agent:${IOTA_NORTH_PORT}
      - IOTA_CB_NGSI_VERSION=v2
      - IOTA_AUTOCAST=true
      - IOTA_AUTH_ENABLED=true
      - IOTA_AUTH_TYPE=oauth2
      - IOTA_AUTH_HEADER=Authorization
      - IOTA_AUTH_HOST=keyrock
      - IOTA_AUTH_PORT=${KEYROCK_PORT}
      - IOTA_AUTH_URL=http://keyrock:${KEYROCK_PORT}
      - IOTA_AUTH_CLIENT_ID=tutorial-dckr-site-0000-xpresswebapp
      - IOTA_AUTH_CLIENT_SECRET=tutorial-dckr-host-0000-clientsecret
      - IOTA_AUTH_PERMANENT_TOKEN=true
      - IOTA_AUTH_TOKEN_PATH=/oauth2/token
    healthcheck:
      interval: 5s
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 60s
        max_attempts: 10

  keyrock:
    image: quay.io/fiware/idm:${KEYROCK_VERSION}
    container_name: fiware-keyrock
    hostname: keyrock
    networks:
      default:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.1.5
    depends_on:
      - mysql-db
      - authzforce
    ports:
      - "${KEYROCK_PORT}:${KEYROCK_PORT}" # localhost:3005
    environment:
      - DEBUG=idm:*
      - IDM_DB_HOST=mysql-db
      - IDM_DB_PASS_FILE=/run/secrets/my_secret_data
      - IDM_DB_USER=root
      - IDM_HOST=http://localhost:${KEYROCK_PORT}
      - IDM_PORT=${KEYROCK_PORT}
      - IDM_HTTPS_PORT=${KEYROCK_HTTPS_PORT}
      - IDM_ADMIN_USER=alice
      - IDM_ADMIN_EMAIL=alice-the-admin@test.com
      - IDM_ADMIN_PASS=test
      - IDM_PDP_LEVEL=advanced
      - IDM_AUTHZFORCE_ENABLED=true
      - IDM_AUTHZFORCE_HOST=authzforce
      - IDM_AUTHZFORCE_PORT=${AUTHZFORCE_PORT}
      - IDM_CSP_FORM_ACTION=*
      - IDM_CORS_ENABLED=true
      - IDM_CORS_ORIGIN=*
      - IDM_CORS_METHODS=*
      - IDM_CORS_ALLOWED_HEADERS=*
      - IDM_CORS_CREDENTIALS=true
      - IDM_CORS_PREFLIGHT=true
      - IDM_CORS_EXPOSED_HEADERS=*
      - IDM_CORS_MAX_AGE=600
    secrets:
      - my_secret_data
    healthcheck:
      interval: 5s
    deploy:
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 60s
        max_attempts: 10

I have configured CORS settings in the docker-compose file for Keyrock as follows:
  - IDM_CORS_ENABLED=true
  - IDM_CORS_ORIGIN=*
  - IDM_CORS_METHODS=*
  - IDM_CORS_ALLOWED_HEADERS=*
  - IDM_CORS_CREDENTIALS=true
  - IDM_CORS_PREFLIGHT=true
  - IDM_CORS_EXPOSED_HEADERS=*
  - IDM_CORS_MAX_AGE=600

I expected these settings to allow all origins, methods, and headers, as well as credentials and preflight requests, to resolve the CORS issue. However, the error persists.
These are the requests :
Request for logging in users:
curl -iX POST \
  'http://localhost:3005/v1/auth/tokens' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "token": "d848eb12-889f-433b-9811-6a4fbf0b86ca"
}'


Request for creating user:
curl -iX POST \
  'http://localhost:3005/v1/users' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'X-Auth-token: {{X-Auth-token}}' \
  -d '{
  "user": {
    "username": "alice",
    "email": "alice@test.com",
    "password": "test"
  }
}'`

This is the CORS error :
Access to fetch at 'http://{valid server-ip}:3005/v1/users' from origin 'http://{valid server-ip}:8989' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

and this is the network tab of the request for creating users :
enter image description here

What CORS error? What does its message say? Edit your question and add this info there.

it's been edited
